# make minimum height based on imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, height

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="400dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/invitation_imageview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
       />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/invitation_avatar_view_1"
        android:layout_width="28dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_margin="6dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Hi all, this is my layout and I have an issue that if i put smaller image for example 60*60 - px to this layout my view is just around 60 pixel tall. but the image is stretched as it should be, I added minimum height to layout, but it does not solve my problem exactly because that number could be different based on the width of the device. What should I do to have always shown my whole imageview and have the wrap content as well, and not to play with some minHeight?

Comment: Use `android:layout_weight`.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean

Comment: @AnoopM unfortinately it does not help the view is still 60 pixel tall. and the imageview is streched correctly